# why file is not deleting ? I/O

Tags: java, encryption, io

hello guyz i have a method that encrypt files in my application, i wanted to encrypt file and delete the source i tried it like this but it wont work.. ?

```
 public static void encrypt(String password, InputStream is, OutputStream os,String DelFile) throws Exception {

SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password(password), "TripleDES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("TripleDES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
byte[] buf = new byte[8096];
os = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
int numRead = 0;
while ((numRead = is.read(buf)) >= 0) {
    os.write(buf, 0, numRead);
}
os.close();

// file deleting part...
File f = new File(DelFile);
f.delete();}
```

this `f.delete();` should be deleted the file? am i right?  but it wont work, 
Please advice, 
Thank you.

Comment: Does it throw an exception?

Comment: Is the InputStream open against the same file?

Comment: @Fildor No exceptions, when i put `f.delete();`  to `System.out.println(f.delete());` it prints false..

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson yes i want to delete the file because when i encrypt the file the original file remain. i dont want that

Comment: @user2136160 You'll need to close the inputstream before deleting the file.

Comment: On a separate point, it looks like the only time you use the DelFile variable is to delete the file. If that is the case, then I think you should take that functionality out of this method. You have built a side effect in to the method that is not immediately apparent. I would expect this method to encrypt an inputstream into an outputstream ( which it does ), but the method also will delete an arbitrary, possibly unrelated file from the file system. That doesn't feel right to me. And, if your problem _is_ due to the inputstream still being open, it'll enable you to restructure your code.

Answer (score 2):

Either there is an inputstream open against that file, or the full file name is not given(along with the path). This is the reason `delete()` method of `File` is not so useful to find the actual reason for not deleting. If you look at its [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete())

> Deletes the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If
> this pathname denotes a directory, then the directory must be empty in
> order to be deleted. Note that the Files class defines the delete
> method to throw an IOException when a file cannot be deleted. This is
> useful for error reporting and to diagnose why a file cannot be
> deleted.

So here is the advice to help you find the root cause. Use the [Files.delete()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)) method for deletion.

**Throws:**

> NoSuchFileException - if the file does not exist (optional specific
> exception)
>
> DirectoryNotEmptyException - if the file is a directory and
> could not otherwise be deleted because the directory is not empty
> (optional specific exception)
>
> IOException - if an I/O error occurs
>
> SecurityException - In the case of the default provider, and a
> security manager is installed, the SecurityManager.checkDelete(String)
> method is invoked to check delete access to the file

Seeing the exception it throws, you can figure out what the root cause is.

Answer (score 0):

Admin rights?
Is it raising an exception? If it is, catch it.

```
try {
Files.delete(path);
} catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
} catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
} catch (IOException x) {
// File permission problems are caught here.
System.err.println(x);
}
```